# Will calling an enum with an object reference as a value create an object every time it's called?

Tags: java, enums

This became my concern mainly because of this:

```
public enum Method {
    POST(new Host().getAssets()),
    GET("GET"),
    DELETE("DELETE"),
    PUT("PUT");

    private String method;

    Method(String s) {
        method = s;
    }

    private String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }
}
```

The `Host` class is Spring `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated to be injected with values from an `application.properties` file at runtime. If I write that as a value of an `enum`, will it create a new object instance of `Host` every time I use Method.POST?

Comment: Shouldn't, theoretically. `POST` should be a singleton. And that should be easy to test (just add a line of logging to the constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It will create instance only once. This can be checked with a print statement like below. Here `getAssets()` and constructor has been called only once:

```
    public class Host {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(Method.POST);
        System.out.println(Method.POST);
        System.out.println(Method.POST);
    }

    Host()
    {
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }

    String getAssets()
    {
        System.out.println("ssssssssssss");
        return "eeee";
    }
}


enum Method {
    POST(new Host().getAssets()),
    GET("GET"),
    DELETE("DELETE"),
    PUT("PUT");

    private String method;

    Method(String s) {
        method = s;
    }

    private String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }
}
```

***O/P:***

```
    Hello World!
--------------
ssssssssssss
POST
POST
POST
```

Answer (score 1):

All `values` of an `Enumerator` are `singletons`, which means, they are initialized once and reused every time you access it. So you can see the "definition" of an Enumerator Value as 'Constructor'.

This also means: if you provide a setter for the property "method" and change its value at runtime, the next access will return the new value! `singleton` does *not* mean its value is `final`.

```
public enum Method {
    POST(new Host().getAssets()), // definition
    GET("GET"),// definition
    DELETE("DELETE"),// definition
    PUT("PUT");// definition

    private String method;

    // Constructor
    Method(String s) {
        method = s;
    }

    private String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }
}
```